# run multiple streaming queries with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a job which writes (in streaming) two different dataframes in two different paths (S3).

I tried several solutions but it doesn't work
below is the code I used in pyspark:

```
query1 = df1.writeStream.format("parquet").option("checkpointLocation",
                                                "checkpoints") \
            .option("path", "output").partitionBy("year", "month", "day").outputMode("append") \
            .start()

query2 = df2.writeStream.format("parquet").option("checkpointLocation",
                                                "checkpoints2") \
            .option("path", "output2").partitionBy("year", "month", "day").outputMode("append") \
            .start()
```

first option:

```
query1.awaitTermination()
query2.awaitTermination()
```

second option :

```
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

But all options don't work, only, the first dataframe gets written

any idea how to fix this please ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work", what is the problem? Do you get an error? What is your expected result? etc.

Comment: I changed my question , only the first dataframe gets written

Comment: what is the  streaming source that you are testing with? is it socket ?